Error while using CrystalDecisions for C#
I am creating a SAP B1 Addon that uses CrystalDecisions to create reports. It works perfectly on my machine, but on the clients machine I got an error saying that it failed to load the report file.

Failed to load file 10616_44924_{CC56A7A6-BC40-424E-A45A-45384BFBED2A}.rpt
at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e)
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSourceInternal(Object val, Type type)
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(DataTable dataTable)

So I searched for it and found two main possible fixes:

The first one is to change useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy true on app config, which did not resolve.

And the second solution is to add the crdb_adoplus.dll to my application directory. When I did it the error about missing report file that I mentioned in the beginning of the text stopped to happen. But the addon crashes, it does throw any exceptions it just crashes, SAP shows the following message:



When I access Windows events there are three events related to the error:


What am I missing on my configuration?
